# Pass a compare function to a class

Tags: c++

I want to be able to create a compare function using a class, eg:

```
bool someClassLess(const someClass &a1, const someClass &a2) {
    return (a1.variable1 < a2.variable1 && a1.variable2 < a2.variable2);
}
```

Then declare a priority queue of **someClass** and pass my compare function to be used when pushing elements, eg:

```
PriorityQueue<someClass> arr(someClassLess());
```

If no compare function is passed when declaring the priority queue, it should automatically use the **less** function in **functional** library when pushing.

**How do I pass a compare function to a class?**

Below you can find code of my selfwritten PriorityQueue. The code includes a failed attempt to pass a compare function.

```
#ifndef PRIORITY_QUEUE_H
#define PRIORITY_QUEUE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::less;

template<typename T>
class PriorityQueue {
public:

    template<typename PRED>
    PriorityQueue(PRED compare);
    ~PriorityQueue();

    T pop();
    void push(const T &e);
    size_t getSize() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void print() const;

private:

    T *end;
    T *queue;
    PRED compare;

};

template<typename T>
PriorityQueue<T>::PriorityQueue(PRED compare = less<T>()) : queue(0), end(0), compare(compare) {
}


template<typename T>
PriorityQueue<T>::~PriorityQueue() {
    delete [] queue;
}

template<typename T>
T PriorityQueue<T>::pop() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        throw "Queue is empty";
    } else if(getSize() == 1) {
        T removed = *queue;
        delete [] queue;
        queue = end = 0;
        return removed;
    }

    T *newQueue = new T[getSize() - 1];
    // Iteratorer
    T *it = queue, *itNew = newQueue;

    T removed = *(it++);
    for( ; it != end; it++, itNew++) {
        *itNew = *it;
    }

    int oldSize = getSize();

    T *tmp = queue;
    queue = newQueue;
    delete [] tmp;

    end = queue + oldSize - 1;

    return removed;
}

template<typename T>
void PriorityQueue<T>::push(const T &e) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        queue = new T[1];
        *queue = e;
        end = queue + 1;
        return;
    }

    T *newQueue = new T[getSize() + 1];
    // Iterators
    T *it = queue, *itNew = newQueue;

    // Find where element e should be inserted, whilst inserting elements
    // compare(*it, e) used to look like *it < e when I was initially creating the class
    for( ; compare(*it, e) && it != end; it++, itNew++) {
        *itNew = *it; 
    }

    // Insert e
    *(itNew++) = e;

    // Insert the remaining elements
    for ( ; it != end; it++, itNew++) {
        *itNew = *it;
    }

    int oldSize = getSize();

    T *tmp = queue;
    queue = newQueue;
    delete [] tmp;

    end = queue + oldSize + 1;
}

template<typename T>
size_t PriorityQueue<T>::getSize() const {
    return (end - queue);
}

template<typename T>
bool PriorityQueue<T>::isEmpty() const {
    return (getSize() <= 0);
}

template<typename T>
void PriorityQueue<T>::print() const {
    for(int *i = queue; i != end; i++) {
        cout << *i << endl;
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: Am I the only one who can't find an actual question? I see what the overall goal is and what you've tried, but no problem stated.

Comment: Why is option 1 ugly? If you make one change, so it looks like `template<typename T, typename Compare=std::less<T> > class PriorityQueue` then you can just say `PriorityQueue<int>` and it will use `std::less<int>` by default, but you can also say `PriorityQueue<int, MyCompare>` if you want. That's how the built-in ordered collections work (e.g. `std::map`)

Comment: @chris I realise I don't have a question. I'll update the text accordingly.

Comment: I know you've 'solved' it at this point, but I wanted to chime in to say that Option 2 is not just ugly - it's dangerous.  The compare function is integral to the priority queue.  Option 2 opens for the possibility of passing different comparators each time you push - that could violate the integrity of your priority queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just shamelessly copy the implementation of [`std::priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/). Just use this:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less< T > >
class PriorityQueue {
  public:
    PriorityQueue(Compare comp = Compare()) : end(0), queue(0), compare(comp) { };

    // ...

  private:

    T *end;
    T *queue;
    Compare compare;

};
```

Comment: Looking at the standard library... so simple, yet so smart! Thanks, this worked fine!

Comment: Some people call this design reuse.  I call it smart.